# Spring cloud data flow and Oracle FCF

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We have experience with Spring XD for the past couple of years and now in process of migrating towards Spring Cloud Data Flow. We are using Oracle RAC cluster as job repository(For HA at database level).

To get true HA with Oracle RAC, JDBC Client need to use connection pool configuration with Oracle Fast Connection Failover(FCF) for event notifications on oracle node failures.

Do we have support in cloud data flow to customize the connection pool so that we can include FCF configurations?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your concerns are and why you are asking for this specifically. Given that, I'll answer why we rely on a database and how it's used.

Spring Cloud Data Flow uses an RDBMS for simple metadata persistence. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms). Oracle happens to be one of the RDBMS that you can use to back SCDF's job-repository.

Apart from the simple connection credentials and the licensed Oracle-driver in the classpath, we don't expect anything else to be specially configured to use Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the response, revised my question with more details